# How to use wmctrl to activate window of a given class?

Tags: linux, window-manager, x-server, wmctrl

The output of `wmctrl -lx` looks like this:

```
0x020002f5  0 Plasma.Plasma         lnx plasma-desktop
0x02a00015  0 okular.Okular         lnx TCP/IP Protocol Suite – Okular
0x032000fe  1 amarok.Amarok         lnx Billy Talent - This Suffering  ::  Amarok
0x03e00001  0 Google-chrome.Google-chrome  lnx wmctrl based on class - Google Search - Google Chrome
0x04400001  1 Chromium.Chromium     lnx openSUSE - Chromium
0x05400050  0 gvim.Gvim             lnx activate_or_run.sh (~/bin/repo) - GVIM
0x04a0001a  0 konsole.Konsole       lnx user@lnx:/home – Konsole
```

I would imagine that 2nd column denotes class of window.

Now I would like to activate the window based on its class rather than its title. Let's say
the chosen window is `gvim.Gvim`.

So I tried `wmctrl -ax gvim.Gvim` or different combinations, surrounding `gvim.Gvim` in quotation marks, using only `gvim` then `Gvim` but to no success.

How can this be done?

Comment: Actually @Arkonix was in the correct track. This works just like the answer: `wmctrl -xa gvim.Gvim`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since `<WIN>` is a parameter of the `-a` option you should run the command as:

```
wmctrl -x -a gvim.Gvim
```